# adding new volunteer project hangs

Tags: civivolunteer

We are running:
civicrm 5.30.0
civi volunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1
angular profiles 4.6-1.0.2

Adding a new volunteer project just hangs showing the timer. Problem present under chrome and firefox. Here is the detail:
volunteer,
new volunteer project,
project title set Dave test 1,
save and done

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! It would be helpful if you could provide some more detail of the exact steps you have taken. This will help people to answer your question. A screenshot might be useful too (but block out any personal details).

Comment: When a page hangs, it's often best to repeat the process by opening the page in a new tab.  You'll often see errors which will make it easier to troubleshoot.  Feel free to edit your question if you find those errors.

Comment: This looks a bit like an error 500 during ajax and so you'd probably need to look in the web server logs, e.g. apache/nginx/etc.

Comment: Thanks Demerit, I will do that

Comment: The server logs indicated an error, we noticed a new version of the angular profiles extension so updated from version 4.6-1.0.2 to 4.7.31-1.1.2 which fixed the problem

Comment: I had this same problem even with Angular Profiles 4.7.31-1.1.2 installed. I upgraded to 5.23-1.2.2 and all was fixed.